# Different functions for each post in loop wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a wordpress loop that uses a template to echo my custom post type upon a page.

It echos the same class names and html structure but different content.

What I want to do is use javascript to add functionality like `onmousemove` to each post and display different content for each post echoed in the loop.

But the thing is that how can I target each post individually when they all have the same class names and the fact that the loop is done before the javascript can even exist so there is no reference.

*Page Template*

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'spark_stars'));  
if (have_posts()) :// Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part('content-stars', get_post_format());
endwhile;
```

*Template Part: content-stars*

```
<div class="entry-content">

    <div class='div' style='display:inline-block;'>
        <a href='<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>'>
            <img style='display:block;' class='star' 
            src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/star_0.png";?>'>
        </a>
        <div class='star_div_text' style='display:none;'>
            <p class='star_text'>
                <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'data_text', true);?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

*Enqueued Javascript*

```
window.star1 = document.getElementsByClassName('star')[0];
star1.onmousemove = function(e)
{   
    // some functions that happen on star1
    // what about star2?
    // how will i reference that or even know how many stars are on the page
}
```

Comment: **pass by value** you can achieve your target...`onmousehove{function($i)}`

Comment: Can you demonstrate that because `star1`is only called when its own event is called. How can you pass anything anywhere when the event is launched and referenced to `star1`?

Comment: ok. you can use **`id`** for `mousehover` function instead of class

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using `this`. For example if you use jquery:

```
$(this).mouseover(function(){
// Function code
)};
```

That is something I would try if I were you.

Besides that you could alsy give an extra class/id so you can still select them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example code

```
 <div class='star_div_text' id='abc' style='display:none;'>
       <p class='star_text'>
           <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'data_text', true);?>
        </p>
  </div>


window.star1 = document.getElementsByClassName('star')[0];
star1.onmousemove = function(e)
{   
   if(this.id == 'abc')
   {
       //do your code
    }
    else{
          //do your code
   }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But I'm using wordpress and all of this is meant to be self managed so I avoid using a method like this because I would not even know how many stars are on the page. Everything is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Daniel:

I understand but $(this) can mean anything. An event would be called if I mouseover anything. What I'm thinking of is something like

```
mouseover{function(e){ // mouseover will know who called
var caller = e || this; // caller will be identified
anotherFunc(caller);  // target that caller
}}
```

Something like this, something dynamic, it should be.

Answer (score 0):

That might be true. If you want to be more specific you could also create a control.
For example:

```
if($('#example').mouseover(function(){
// $(this).*function*();
)};
```

If you would like you could for example replace '#example' to an html tag like `'a'`. Or if you want to use this on more tags `$('#example','#anotherexample').mouseover(function(){   });`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the post ID to reference the div you wish to manipulate via JavaScript

Example 1:
I will create an ID for the target div in this naming convention : starPOSTID

```
<div class='star_div_text' style='display:none;' id="star<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
        <p class='star_text'>
            <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'data_text', true);?>
        </p>
</div>
```

so you can  reference star1 in your javascript.

Example 2:
Preferably i suggest you use Jquery to selector for this.

```
$("star_div_text").mousemove(function(){
  $("star_div_text").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

You learn more about Jquery here : http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help but I have found the solution.

First of all I calculated how many items had the same class names. Then I assigned an event listener to all of them. When the event handler was called I ran a loop to identify the caller. When the caller was identified I passed it to another function to handle it.

Something like this

*Html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class='a' style='width:100px; height:100px; background:orange;'></div>
    <div class='a' style='width:100px; height:100px; background:tomato;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Javascript*

```
<script>
a = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
l = a.length;

for (var i = 0; i<l; i++)
{
    a[i].addEventListener('click',analyse); // add event to all classes
}

function analyse()
{
    for (var i = 0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if (this == a[i]) // is this the class that was clicked
        {
            var arg = this; // identified
            anotherFunc(arg);
        }       
    }
}

function anotherFunc(e)
{
    console.log(e); // The class that got clicked even though all have the same name
}
</script>
```

Comment: but how could you identify target on each post individually?[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/jmhkh11d/)..in alert it is not identify?

Comment: I identify each post individually by the **if statement** in `function analyse()`. So when an event is called, though they all have the same event callers, it only happens on one element.

 I looked at your code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/jmhkh11d/) and there was one error. Change onmouseover to mouseover.

Comment: dude,edited link not working. and i agree with u..it only happens on one element. but how could you do that..star1-->funtion1(), star2-->function2()..for every post.

Comment: I did not edit the link: to make it work, all you are to do is  change `onmouseover` to `mouseover`. And that kind of method is just not going to work out if you have like 100 stars. Sure, if you have a limited number of stars then you could easily target the stars like this `star[0], star[1], star[2]`. But imagine if at one time you had 2 stars then the next minute you have 40 stars. That is my situation. But I guess when you have many stars like that, you could write an array of functions, put it in a for loop and for every star there would be a different function (of your choice in order).